# Right Join not showing null values (or is there something wrong besides the code)

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I can only extract 196 values from k$portfolio using right join. But as you can see, I specified 600+ values in the kp.id parameter. I already tried different kinds of join. I am expecting to get 600+ values, including the ones with null. I am currently getting only 196, those with have existing values in k$internal_role.

Sorry code is clumsy with all the 'in parameter' but i've been used to this.

```
select kp.match_code,kp.description,ka.description, kct.description 
from k$portfolio kp
right outer join k$internal_role kir on kir.portfolio = kp.id 
join k$actors ka on ka.id = kir.actor and role = 11
join k$client kc on kc.id = kp.client
join k$client_types kct on kct.id = kc.type
where portfolio id in 
('55826',
'55827',
'55828',
'58622',
etc etc. 600 plus number of values)
order by kp.description
```

Comment: the 'portfolio id in' in reality contains 600+ values, I edited it over here to avoid a messy post.

Comment: There's no outer join of any kind in code you posted.

Comment: fixed it sir, same result though

Comment: No idea, we don't have your data. I suggest you start over by adding table-by-table into the FROM clause and see what's going on.

Comment: `where portfolio id in` is invalid syntax; I'm assuming you mean `where kp.id in`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: When pinned down via a MRE this is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: LEFT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Similarly for RIGHT JOIN ON & right table rows. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON, a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right/left [sic] table column to be not NULL removes rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. `(kir.portfolio = kp.id` so portfolio is not null but you have `where portfolio id in`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `OUTER JOIN` the `k$internal_role` and then you `INNER JOIN` the `k$actors` tables to that which will force that former join to also behave as an `INNER JOIN`; so, to fix it, you need to `OUTER JOIN` the `k$actors` table too.

However, if I've got the sample data correct, you also want to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than `RIGHT`:

```sql
SELECT kp.match_code,
       kp.description,
       ka.description,
       kct.description 
FROM   k$portfolio kp
       INNER JOIN k$client kc
       ON ( kc.id = kp.client )
       INNER JOIN k$client_types kct
       ON ( kct.id = kc.type )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN k$internal_role kir
       ON ( kir.portfolio = kp.id )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN k$actors ka
       ON ( ka.id = kir.actor and role = 11 )
WHERE  kp.id in (
        55826,
        55827,
        55828,
        58622
      )
ORDER BY
      kp.description
```

So, for some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE k$portfolio ( id, client, match_code, description ) AS
SELECT 55826, 1, 'AA', 'Portfolio1'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 55827, 1, 'BB', 'Portfolio2'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 55828, 2, 'CC', 'Portfolio3'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 58622, 3, 'DD', 'Portfolio4'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE k$client ( id, type ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE k$client_types ( id, description ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Type2' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE k$internal_role ( portfolio, actor, role ) AS
SELECT 55826, 1, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 55828, 2, 12 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE k$actors ( id, description ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Actor1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Actor2' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> MATCH_CODE | DESCRIPTION | DESCRIPTION | DESCRIPTION
> :--------- | :---------- | :---------- | :----------
> AA         | Portfolio1  | Actor1      | Type1      
> BB         | Portfolio2  | null        | Type1      
> CC         | Portfolio3  | null        | Type1      
> DD         | Portfolio4  | null        | Type2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bcced18b7c50d6c1ebba44e79436b5c7)*